# Can we create tag [ipfs]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I'm becoming more active in the community and that comes from being atm working with IPFS and some other devops/sysadmin tools.

Generally speaking I see tasks related with IPFS in Ethereum community but given that I'm not working with Ethereum, this seems to be the most appropriate community. [Others, like Robert Longson, think the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413707/5675325).

Could we create an IPFS tag? That'd be great... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you found a question you want to tag IPFS?  Any questions can be tagged with any appropriate tag. Start by asking questions about IPFS, the tag will follow!

Comment: Yes Peter Turner. I've asked two questions related with IPFS already

Comment: For posterity, in case anyone's wondering: Looks like Peter created the [tag:ipfs] tag and added it to those 2 questions on December 20 :)